# Number of valid NxN Takuzu Boards a.k.a 0h h1 (details inside)?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, puzzle

Takuzu a logic puzzle which has a $N \times N$ grid filled with $0$'s and $1$'s following these rules:

1. Every row/column has equal number of $0$'s and $1$'s
2. No two rows/columns are same
3. No three adjacent (all three horizontal or all three vertical) numbers are same

For more details: [Takuzu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takuzu). It has also been recently popular as the game [*0h h1*](http://www.0hh1.com/)

I was wondering how many number of boards of size $N \times N$ ($N$ is even) are possible?

For any odd $N$ it's $0$ (Since rule 1 would be violated), For $N=2$, it is $2$, i.e the boards $[01,10]$ and $[10,01]$, For $N=4$, I think it is $72$ but I'm not pretty sure, For any other $N$ I'm not sure how to count them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard problem and I doubt it's been studied seriously. However, my computer tells me that for the first few boards, you can get:

- 2 x 2 ... 2
- 4 x 4 ... 72
- 6 x 6 ... 4,140
- 8 x 8 ... 4,111,116

After that my algorithm is too slow to keep going.

I searched on OEIS for any variation of this sequence but couldn't find it. So I double-checked with a different method and then tried to type it into the database, at which point the website warned me that the sequence was already there — it was just too recent and hadn't been accepted yet! Almost certainly, it's there because you asked about the problem.

I was worried about stealing somebody's thunder, but it's been a week, and it's published, so here it is: [A253316](https://oeis.org/A253316). Unfortunately, at the moment the answer for 10 x 10 is still a mystery.

Comment: Never thought it would be such a hard problem. Really wonder if someone can figure out a formula or even a feasible algorithm for the higher orders.